# VIM: disabling the cursor/arrow keys, but only for navigation

Tags: vim

```
inoremap  <Up>     <NOP>
inoremap  <Down>   <NOP>
inoremap  <Left>   <NOP>
inoremap  <Right>  <NOP>
noremap   <Up>     <NOP>
noremap   <Down>   <NOP>
noremap   <Left>   <NOP>
noremap   <Right>  <NOP>
```

This is what I use to disable cursor navigation, to help me stick to hjkl :)

But it also disables the cursor on the command bar... normally the arrow keys let you cycle through the history

Is it possible to disable the cursor keys ONLY for navigation, and not for the history?

Comment: Thank you, this is the first time I get the answer from the question!

Comment: In insert mode, my `up` and `down` keys still work. Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 34):

Add the following in your `.vimrc` file:

```
" Disable Arrow keys in Normal mode
map <up> <nop>
map <down> <nop>
map <left> <nop>
map <right> <nop>

" Disable Arrow keys in Insert mode
imap <up> <nop>
imap <down> <nop>
imap <left> <nop>
imap <right> <nop>
```

Answer (score 26):

You can cycle through the history using `C-n` and `C-p` (Ctrl+n and Ctrl+p, respectively).

Comment: This is about the correct solution. If you want to keep your hands on the home row, then you keep your hands there!

Comment: @misha I want to echo out "Stop being stupid" when using arrow keys along with disabling those keys. Can you tell me what do I need to put into .vimrc. I don't know VimScript.

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan you saw that talk, didn't you? :) anyway, the line you're looking for is something like: `map <up> :echoerr "Stop being stupid"<CR>`

Answer (score 10):

The code you have posted should not disable history navigation in command line mode, are you sure you don't have `cnoremap <Up> <Nop>` or `noremap! <Up> <Nop>` somewhere? Try `verbose cmap <Up>` it should show you whether `<Up>` key is redefined for command line mode.

---

If when saying «command bar» you meant command-line window, you could try the following:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Up> ((bufname("%") is# "[Command Line]")?("\<Up>"):(""))
```

Comment: Thank you for these responses...... both very usefull, and yes my history DOES actually work with the arrow keys - I had a conflicting issue that made it appear as if it didn't :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the CmdWinEnter autocmd event to unmap arrow keys for the command-line window.

Comment: `cnoremap` works to disable the up arrows in command line mode.. Thanks..

Answer (score 7):

For me, this works:

```
map <Left> <Nop>
map <Right> <Nop>
map <Up> <Nop>
map <Down> <Nop>
```

Taken from:
https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc#L148

Answer (score 2):

Use `q:` to open a split window of your command line. You can navigate within it normally, as it's a regular vim window using `hjkl` and the other usual vim motions, and hit enter to run the command under cursor.

Don't use the arrow keys to navigate in the command line history.

Incidentally, you can also access your search history using `q/` or `q?`.

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider remapping them to move between the split windows.
This disables the arrow keys for directional movement inside the file but lets you move between the split windows.

```
noremap <up> <C-w><up>
noremap <down> <C-w><down>
noremap <left> <C-w><left>
noremap <right> <C-w><right>
```

Comment: If one is a heavy user of windows, using arrows instead of the native ctlr+w j/h/k/l is gonna slow them down, imho.

Answer (score 0):

Change `noremap` to `nnoremap` to apply the mappings to normal mode, otherwise they're global all-modes mappings.

Comment: -1: They are not all-modes. They are only normal, operator-pending, select and visual mode mappings.