# Why do I need to press escape twice to cancel a vim search?

Tags: vim

Often I search for something and realize halfway through the search there are no matches. To cancel the search, I have to press escape twice. I've removed my entire .vimrc file to see what plugin is causing this. Curiously, if I have no .vimrc file, I need only press escape once. **Even if I have an empty .vimrc file, I need to press escape twice.**

If I have haya14busa/incsearch.vim installed, I have to press escape twice and wait for a second before the search is cancelled. This is cumbersome.

Comment: If you're running in a terminal, the lag is likely caused by the fact that `Esc` is used in combination with other keys to implement things like the [arrow and function keys](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8488537/155299).  The difference in behavior is probably due to `nocompatible` being set by default when a `.vimrc` file is present.

Answer (score 7):

Originally, a "terminal" was a physical device you had at your office which consisted of a screen, a keyboard, and some very basic circuitry to communicate over a (usually) serial line. It would communicate to a big "mainframe" computer which would accept logins from dozens or even hundreds of users. A modern "terminal emulator" (xterm, iterm, or whatever you use) is nothing more than a software emulation of one of those physical terminals; with all the limitations that this entails.

The *only* way terminals could communicate with the mainframe was through this serial line and the keyboard interface. This is why the ASCII character set has 32 so-called "control-characters" to control various aspects of the communication and/or send special messages to the mainframe. These control codes were sent by holding down the Control key and pressing a letter (hence the name of that key).

You're probably familiar with some of these codes, but others are no longer used. The Escape code is one of them: number 27, usually represented as `^[` (it has its own dedicated key on most keyboards, but pressing Control+[ will do exactly the same).

The problem is that 31 codes is hardly enough for all features on a modern keyboard: Arrow keys, Insert, F1-12, etc.
So what most terminal emulators do is send a sequence of characters starting with the escape character to indicate some special meaning. For example on my system my keyboard sends `^[OP` (three characters: escape and then "OP"), and the "arrow up" sends `^[[A`. These codes may differ on your system, but they should be 2 or 3 characters (you can check it in your shell or Vim's insert mode by pressing `^V` and then the key).

All of this works, but with some caveats. If an application receives an escape character then it must decide if we want to use escape or if it's the start of a special escape sequence such as the arrow keys or F1. Another caveat is that pressing "escape O P" in quick succession can actually trigger F1.

So Vim wait for a bit to see if we're using escape or a key sequence. You can control this timeout with the [`:help 'timeoutlen'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27timeoutlen%27) setting; it's set to one second by default; but on most machines setting it to e.g. 200 is probably fine. It may cause issues over slower connections such as ssh, though.

Note that gVim doesn't suffer from this problem, as this doesn't use a terminal emulator to rely on its keyboard input. The rest of the world has moved on since the 1960s, and graphical interfaces have *significantly* more advanced and powerful keyboard input.