# Why does the Vim mapping that maps the ESC key to clear text highlighting cause strange behavior in vim?

Tags: macos, vim, highlight

**Background:**
I'm using the terminal version of Vim.  I found [this guide](https://thevaluable.dev/vim-search/) mentioning a way to use the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to clear highlighted text from a previous regex search.

Putting the mapping `map <esc> :noh<cr>` into my `vimrc` file does produce the desired effect...**BUT**:

(1): It causes vim to start in "Replace" mode
(2): It breaks the arrow keys (they don't move the cursor, but insert characters instead).

In [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting/25569434), it is addressed that using the mapping `nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>` will do the job, but works without issues only with a GUI, and causes problems when not using a GUI (my situation).

Can this mapping be fixed? If not, why can't I use the escape key to clear text highlighting.

My vim version is: `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1`

Comment: What problems when not using vim with a GUI?

Comment: @Ry- I tried to clarify it - I'm not using a GUI. It causes problems when **not** using the GUI. That is, my situation.

Comment: Just to confirm, you mean `nnoremap` has exactly the same issue as `map`?

Comment: Yes. They seem to cause the same issue.

Comment: Just do not map <esc>, this is silly. You can map some other key (usual advice is `nnoremap <C-L> :noh<CR><C-L>` -- CTRL-L is normally used to redraw the screen in Vim).

Comment: I agree with @Matt.

Comment: There are definitely questions along similar lines at [vi.se] if you care to dig around

Comment: Backing up @matt's suggestion, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8488537/155299

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and decided to map `<ESC><ESC>` (push <kbd>ESC</kbd> twice) instead. I am no longer having issues.

```
nnoremap <ESC><ESC> :noh<CR>
```